# Bookshelf - get the id when a new record is created

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I'm using bookshelf with mysql for my project and can't figure out how I can get the id when I'm creating a new record. Instead it just returns undefined.

```
// model.js
const User = bookshelf.model('User', {
  tableName: 'user',
  hidden: ['password']
});

// main.js
User.forge(attributes)
    .save()
    .then(function (newRow) {
      console.log(newRow.id); // Should return the id
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      // Handle errors
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`newRow` object contains fields only from `attributes`. To get row id we need to read this row from database.

Possibly this is a crutch, but I don't know a better solution.

```js
const User = bookshelf.model('User', {
  tableName: 'user',
  hidden: ['password']
});

// main.js
User.forge(attributes)
    .save()
    .then(function (newRow) {
      console.log(newRow.id); // undefined
      User.where(attributes).fetch()
        .then((createdUser) => {
          console.log(createdUser); // any id (1 for example)
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          // Handle errors
        });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      // Handle errors
    });
```

P.S Better to use javascript `async`/`await` syntax intead of `Promise.then()`/`Promise.catch()`

```js
const User = bookshelf.model('User', {
  tableName: 'user',
  hidden: ['password']
});

// main.js (in a async function)
try {
  const newRow = await User.forge(attributes).save();
  console.log(newRow.id); // undefined
  const createdUser = await User.where(attributes).fetch();
  console.log(createdUser); // any id (1 for example)
} catch (err) {
  // Handle errors
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const User = bookshelf.model('User', {
  tableName: 'user',
  hidden: ['password']
});

// main.js
const user = await new User().save(attributes);
const {id} = user.toJSON()
```

or

```
const User = bookshelf.model('User', {
  tableName: 'user',
  hidden: ['password']
});

// main.js
User.forge(attributes)
    .save()
    .then(function (newRow) {
      let {id} = newRow.toJSON();
      console.log(id); // Should return the id
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      // Handle errors
});
```

The problem is that you are not calling `toJSON` to serialize.